# Siddhi Writing custom aggregation function

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-cep

I'm building a custom aggregation function in siddhi an I have doubts about the oficial documentation, placed at https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Writing+a+Custom+Aggregate+Function

In the example it creates "an aggregate function extension with **custom** as the namespace and **std** as the function name", so my first question is, why then, when it invokes the function from siddhi, it uses:

```
from pizzaOrder#window.length(20)
select custom:count(orderNo) as totalOrders
insert into orderCount;
```

should not be like this instead?

```
from pizzaOrder#window.length(20)
select custom:std(orderNo) as totalOrders
insert into orderCount;
```

the second question I have is related to the custom.siddhiext extension mapping file, as far as I understand it, in this file we have to reference our new class with the newly created function, so, I would write something like this

```
std=org.wso2.siddhi.extension.customAggregateFunction.CountAggregateFunction
```

but again, it uses

```
std=org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.attribute.aggregator.StrandedDeviationAggregateFunction
```

Where does the StrandedDeviationAggregateFunction came from? And using that extension mapping file, ¿how siddhi knows where to find the new count function?

**UPDATED**

I finally used the documentation placed at https://docs.wso2.com/display/SIDDHIEXTENSIONS/Creating+a+Siddhi+Extension+and+Publishing+in+WSO2+Store to generate the aggregation function through maven. But I can't still use the new aggregation function.

Aggregation class:

```
package org.wso2.extension.siddhi.aggregation.string_utils;

import org.wso2.siddhi.core.config.ExecutionPlanContext;
import org.wso2.siddhi.core.executor.ExpressionExecutor;
import org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.attribute.aggregator.AttributeAggregator;
import org.wso2.siddhi.query.api.definition.Attribute;

/**
 * This Sample implemented for count you can implement based on this sample.
 */
public class string_utilsAggregateFunction extends AttributeAggregator {

    private static Attribute.Type type = Attribute.Type.STRING;
    private String value = "";

    /**
     * The initialization method for string_utilsAggregatorFunction.
     *
     * @param attributeExpressionExecutors are the executors of each attributes in the function.
     * @param executionPlanContext         Execution plan runtime context.
     */
    @Override
    protected void init(ExpressionExecutor[] attributeExpressionExecutors, ExecutionPlanContext executionPlanContext) {
    }

    public Attribute.Type getReturnType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * The process add method of the string_utilsAggregateFunction, used when zero or one function parameter is provided.
     *
     * @param data null if the function parameter string_utils is zero or runtime data value of the function parameter.
     * @return the string_utils value.
     */
    @Override
    public Object processAdd(Object data) {
        //Sample code.
        value = value + "," + data.toString();
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * The process add method of the string_utilsAggregateFunction, used when more than one function parameters are provided.
     *
     * @param data the data values for the function parameters.
     * @return the string_utils value.
     */
    @Override
    public Object processAdd(Object[] data) {
        //Sample code.
        value = value + "," + data.toString();
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * The process remove method of the string_utilsAggregateFunction, used when zero or one function parameter is provided.
     *
     * @param data null if the function parameter string_utils is zero or runtime data value of the function parameter.
     * @return the string_utils value.
     */
    @Override
    public Object processRemove(Object data) {
        return value;
        //Sample code.

    }

    /**
     * The process remove method of the string_utilsAggregateFunction, used when more than one function parameters are provided.
     *
     * @param data the data values for the function parameters.
     * @return the string_utils value.
     */
    @Override
    public Object processRemove(Object[] data) {
        //Sample code.
        return value;

    }

    /**
     * Reset string_utils value.
     *
     * @return reset value.
     */
    @Override
    public Object reset() {
        //Sample code.
        value = "";
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * This will be called only once and this can be used to acquire
     * required resources for the processing element.
     * This will be called after initializing the system and before
     * starting to process the events.
     */
    @Override
    public void start() {
        //Nothing to start.
    }

    /**
     * This will be called only once and this can be used to release
     * the acquired resources for processing.
     * This will be called before shutting down the system.
     */
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        //nothing to stop.
    }

    /**
     * Used to collect the serializable state of the processing element, that need to be
     * persisted for the reconstructing the element to the same state on a different point of time.
     *
     * @return stateful objects of the processing element as an array.
     */
    @Override
    public Object[] currentState() {
        return new Object[]{value};
    }

    /**
     * Used to restore serialized state of the processing element, for reconstructing
     * the element to the same state as if was on a previous point of time.
     *
     * @param state the stateful objects of the element as an array on
     *              the same order provided by currentState().
     */
    @Override
    public void restoreState(Object[] state) {
        //Sample code.
        value = (String) state[0];
    }
}
```

siddhiext file:

```
#
# Copyright (c) 2016, WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights Reserved.
#
# WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
# Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
# in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

string_utilsAggregator=org.wso2.extension.siddhi.aggregation.string_utils.string_utilsAggregateFunction
```

when I try to use this method in an execution plan it says "string_utilsAggregator is neither a function extension nor an aggregated attribute extension in execution plan". The stauts of the module(checked through  -DosgiConsole) is ACTIVE. Any idea what is missing?

Comment: There was a problem with the documentation page: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Writing+a+Custom+Aggregate+Function and it is fixed now.

Comment: To find the cause of the error `string_utilsAggregator is neither a function extension nor an aggregated attribute extension in execution plan` need to look at your execution plan as well. If your question is still valid (after related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729093/siddhi-cep-aggregate-the-string-values-of-grouped-events-in-a-batch-time-window/49899596#49899596 being answered), please update the question with the execution plan.